# How can I use Movie Maker in Windows 7 to edit .mp3 audio file?

Tags: audio, windows-movie-maker

As mentioned [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/movie-maker-file-types-faq), the Movie Maker program can use .mp3 audio file but I'm not sure how to do it. It seems like this tool always require a video content.

Comment: Not sure about WMM, but why don't you use a better audio editing program such as Audacity? Of course, MP3 being a lossy format you'll lose quality every time you edit.

Comment: Audacity is a nice tool to edit audio file though it is quite hard to use. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I just want to use the built-in application available right in Windows 7